# Polymer paper ripple

Tags: javascript, jquery, polymer, material-design, polymer-1.0

I am trying to change the color of an element when a button is pressed.
I want a paper ripple effect to be triggered in that element when the button is pressed and the color changes.

How am I supposed to do that?

Target element:

```
<paper-toolbar class="abc">
    <paper-icon-button icon="menu" paper-drawer-toggle></paper-icon-button>
    <div flex class="indent title">Heading</div>
</paper-toolbar>
```

Trigger element:

```
<paper-button class="def background-blue"></paper-button>
<paper-button class="def background-red"></paper-button>
```

Javascript:

```
$(".def").click(function(){
    $(".abc").css("background-color", $(this).css("background-color"));
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of manipulating styles directly on the `paper-toolbar`, a more *element* approach is to add a `paper-ripple` element next to your `paper-toolbar` and manually call `downAction`/`upAction` when `mousedown`/`mouseup` is invoked on your `paper-button`s.

```
<paper-header-panel class="fit">
    <paper-toolbar class="toolbar">
        <paper-icon-button icon="menu" paper-drawer-toggle></paper-icon-button>
        <div flex class="indent title">Heading</div>

        <paper-ripple id="ripple" center></paper-ripple>
    </paper-toolbar> 

    <div>
        <paper-button class="def background-blue"raised on-mousedown="_onMousedown" on-mouseup="_onMouseup">Go blue</paper-button>
        <paper-button class="def background-red" raised on-mousedown="_onMousedown" on-mouseup="_onMouseup">Go red</paper-button>
    </div>
</paper-header-panel>
```

Note that the *background color* of `paper-ripple` is `color`.

```
_assignColor: function(e) {
     var button = Polymer.dom(e).localTarget;
     var ripple = this.$.ripple;

     $(ripple).css("color", $(button).css("background-color"));  

     // or without jQuery
     //var buttonStyle = getComputedStyle(button, null);
     //ripple.style.color = buttonStyle.backgroundColor;        
},

 _onMousedown: function (e) {
    this._assignColor(e);

     this.$.ripple.downAction({x: e.x, y: e.y});
 },

 _onMouseup: function (e) {
     this._assignColor(e);

     this.$.ripple.upAction();
 }
```

Have a look at this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/PAAgq3QoiSMSnGUVWf6A?p=preview).

Comment: Thanks :)
This is what i exacly wanted to do [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/EmE9Iq?p=preview)

Comment: If it helps, consider accepting it as the answer! :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do here, but Polymer takes care of most of the heavy lifting for you. If you just want to style the color of the ripple effect, the [docs](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-button) suggest using the selector:

```
#my-button::shadow paper-ripple {
  color: blue;
}
```

If you want to more permanently change the color of the button, something like the `toggles` attribute might help. (Google's demo is [here](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-button?view=demo:demo/index.html&active=paper-button))

html:

```
<paper-button toggles>button text</paper-button>
```

css:

```
#my-button[active] {
  background-color: red;
}
```

although if you'd want to keep it that color you'd have to set up the button to ignore further click events so it kept its `active` attribute.

Comment: I guess you didn't get what I was trying to do. Anyways the questions has already been solved. Here is the link to what I exactly wanted to do [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/EmE9Iq?p=preview).